# Excel - fill cell when the date in cell falls within a range of dates

Tags: excel, date, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet that has a single column ('I') with dates in it.  I would like the cells in this column to change colour depending on the Quarter that the date falls in.

Dates falling in the range;

- DEC-FEB = RED
- MAR-MAY = GREEN
- JUN-AUG = BLUE
- SEPT-NOV = YELLOW

All dates are formatted as dates (dd/mm/yyyy)

I've tried a range of IF/AND statements but keep getting hung up on the year, and to be honest, I've forgotten most of what I've tried.  Sorry for the lack of info, i tried posting a screenshot but got knocked back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=OR(MONTH(I2)=12,MONTH(I2)=1,MONTH(I2)=2)
=OR(MONTH(I2)=3,MONTH(I2)=4,MONTH(I2)=5)
=OR(MONTH(I2)=6,MONTH(I2)=7,MONTH(I2)=8)
=OR(MONTH(I2)=9,MONTH(I2)=10,MONTH(I2)=11)
```

Note, I'm assuming you have a header row, hence these formula reference I2.

Comment: interestingly, these work for the dec-feb, mar-may, sept-nov quarters, but when i enter a date in the range of jun-aug, the cell ABOVE gets the blue fill and the cell with the data goes white (regardless of what the date/colour was before hand)  I don't see any difference in the way the query is written, or the cells it applies to (=$I:$I)

Comment: scratch that, for some reason the reference to the cell in your query (I2) had changed to 'I1' in each of the other rules, changing this in the blue quarter to reflect 'I1 'as in the other rules, fixed the problem. Cheers =)